# Trying to use shouldValidate

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

So I have a rather complicated little form.

I have a validate function that needs to access nextProps.  [The shouldValidate prop](http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-shouldvalidate-params-boolean-optional-) looks perfect however for some reason the validate function is being called twice, once by shouldValidate and once by the regular validate process. If I remove the first validate property then no validation occurs.

Has anyone got an example of how this works.

I have:

```
AddJobsForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'addJobsForm',
  validate,
  shouldValidate: validate
})(AddJobsForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this in a while, but I think you need to re-read the doc you linked to for what you should be passing into `shouldValidate`.  It's supposed to return a boolean indicating whether `validate` should be called.  It never makes sense for this to be the validate function itself.  If you always want to validate, don't supply anything for `shouldValidate`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something,  Thanks Ed